# node.js fs Readstream event handler never called in Node 12.3.1

Tags: node.js, node-modules, chromium-embedded, nwjs, nwjs-contexts

In custom build CEF-74 with nodeJS 12.3.1 -> we're loading a webApp from which we're downloading images from google drive and google photos, first time downloading of image works fine, but for already downloaded images, node.js fs.CreateReadStream() event handler checks MD5 hash of local file, determines that the asset has already been downloaded.

which is not working here in this case unless we enable --mixed-context on.

what role does --mixed-context might be playing here to make this workflow of md5 hash work?

Comment: It's not clear how exactly this hash you mentioned is stored in the application, but that's actually what the question is.